# Clear file before writing with open()

Tags: c, file

With `fopen`, by setting it to `w` will automatically clear the file for me. However now I'm trying to do the same thing with `open`,

```
int file = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

This won't guarantee that the file is empty and write at the beginning(?). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is it so hard to read [the actual man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger See comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `O_TRUNC` - Initially clear all data from the file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that when I was reading the manual page a while ago!

Answer (score 1):

```
O_TRUNC flag truncates the file when opening. It can be used.  
int file = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT  | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```