# C: implementation of > does not replace file

Tags: c, file-io, pipe

I am implementing the operator > in c for my own "shell".
However, when typing in "cat new.txt > new2.txt" some strange things happen:

```
> cat new.txt
This is a file. 
This file contains some text.

> cat new2.txt
This is also afile. 
This file also contains some text.
This file is called new2.txt.

> cat new.txt > new2.txt

> cat new2.txt
This is a file. 
This file contains some text.
me text.
This file is called new2.txt.
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? I expect new2.txt to be deleted and then written to.

Then line where I redirect the data is:

```
...
pipe(pipefd);
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
  int fd = open(filename[OUT], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(fd);
  execvp(par[0], par);
  exit(-1);
}
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
close(pipefd[READ]);
close(pipefd[WRITE]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear file before writing with open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642756/clear-file-before-writing-with-open)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left off `O_TRUNC` in the `open` flags. Oddly, [you're the second person this evening to make that mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642756/clear-file-before-writing-with-open).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly now. I guess I should totally take a break :D

Comment: Shouldn't this be a "vote to close / duplicate of..." instead of an answer?

Comment: @DevSolar: I really don't know when something counts as a duplicate. The fundamental error is a duplicate, but the question is substantially different.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The *question* is different because the OP was unable (not willing?) to actually isolate the problem (as the OP of that other question did -- but then, *that* noteable was unable / unwilling to read the manpage of the function he was using). As long as answers in a linked question *solve the problem*, it's a duplicate. Ideally, we would have only *one* set of answers for every *cause* of a problem... but this is the internet. ;-) Have an upvote, anyway.